# Are you able to prove the Hibernate Lazy-Loading?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I just want to ask, how to prove that hibernate is doing lazy loading . 
I have code like this :

[image]

And I try to test lazy loading in hibernate (jpa) with this code :

[image]

Actually, I don't wont to load "alamat" property, because that's a TEXT. But when I try to debug the code, I get the output trace like this :

[image]

Hibernate is still select alamat column, and in the debug veriable, I found that Hibernate is really load alamat column :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Hibernate manual notes:

> To enable property level lazy fetching, your classes have to be
>   instrumented: bytecode is added to the original class to enable such
>   feature, please refer to the Hibernate reference documentation. If
>   your classes are not instrumented, property level lazy loading is
>   silently ignored.

How to achieve this is explained in [chapter 20.1.8. Using lazy property fetching](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazyproperties) of the manual. It requires a special build process.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable bytecode instrumentation to activate lazy loading for properties. If you don't have bytecode instrumentation enabled, Hibernate will ignore any properties about lazy loading ([see the docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazyproperties))